# How to Use Another Gem Source With Bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

So I know that I can specify another remote source in my Gemfile, like

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://my-gem-location'
```

For my use case I want this to be S3 (I can create an http address to the gem there).

What I am confused about is what format the gem should be at this endpoint. Right now its just a series of directories and .rb files which doesn't work. I get an error like:

```
Fetching source index from http://my-remote-repo
Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://my-remote-repo
Retrying source fetch due to error (3/3): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from http://my-remote-repo
Could not fetch specs from http://my-remote-repo
```

I figured if its zipped or something that might help but my testing leads to nothing but this error. I also could not find much helpful documentation on hosting remote gems. Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem should be in .gem format to do that you need to do:

```
gem build <yougemname>.gemspec
```

You can find comprehensive information on creating a gem here:

http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

Hope it helps!

Comment: I completely forgot about building the gem! I still get the error from S3 however which is a totally different issue.